# Knapsack dynamic programming - Why are below 2 codes (similar implementation) giving different answers for a test case?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I need to solve the below knapsack problem to maximize value while staying within the knapsack's weight W.

- n is the number of items available
- W is the weight capacity of knapsack
- wt is the weight vector of the n items
- val is the value vector of the n items

I have implemented the below 2 codes. The first one is giving me the right response(216), however the second one is giving me 205, but 216 is what I should be getting for the test case below.
(The smaller test cases for both the codes function properly.)

Both codes are built on the same rationale.
Could someone kindly explain why the second one is giving me the incorrect response for the aforementioned test case?

```
n = 29
W = 41
val = [57, 95, 13, 29, 1, 99, 34, 77, 61, 23, 24, 70, 73, 88, 33, 61, 43, 5, 41, 63, 8, 67, 20, 72, 98, 59, 46, 58, 64]
wt = [83, 84, 85, 76, 13, 87, 2, 23, 33, 82, 79, 100, 88, 85, 91, 78, 83, 44, 4, 50, 11, 68, 90, 88, 73, 83, 46, 16, 7]
```

Code 1

```
#Function to return max value that can be put in knapsack of capacity W.
    def knapSack(W, wt, val, n):
       
        # code here
        def hlpr(W, wt, val, n, d):
            if (n == 0):
                return 0
            if ((W, n) in d.keys()):
                return(d[(W, n)])
            if (W < wt[n-1]):
                d[(W, n)] = hlpr(W, wt, val, n-1, d)
            else:
                d[(W, n)] = max(val[n-1] + hlpr(W-wt[n-1], wt, val, n - 1, d),
                                 hlpr(W, wt, val, n-1, d))
            return(d[(W, n)])
        
        d = {}
        return(hlpr(W, wt, val, n, d))
```

Code 2

```
def knapSack(W, wt, val, n):
       
        # code here
        def helper(W, wt, val, n, d, op):
            if(n == 0):
                return op
            if((W, n) in d):
                return d[(W, n)]
            if(W - wt[n-1] < 0):
                d[(W, n)] = helper(W, wt, val, n-1,d, op)
                return d[(W, n)]
            d[(W, n)] = max(helper(W-wt[n-1], wt, val, n-1, d, op+val[n-1]), helper(W, wt, val, n-1, d, op))
            return d[(W, n)]
        d = {}
        return helper(W, wt, val, n, d, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can first simplify the problem by removing the weights > 41 since the knapsack’s capacity is 41.
This will reduce the problem to the below:

n = 8

W = 41

val = [1, 34, 77, 61, 41, 8, 58, 64]

wt = [13, 2, 23, 33, 4, 11, 16, 7]

Now if we monitor the dictionary while debugging both the codes, we can see that,

the first code saves the following in it's dictionary:

d[(W, n)]   = k

Indicates for capacity W and number of elements n ( [0 to (n-1)] elements ),  the optimal value we can obtain is k

Where as in the second code, it saves the following in it's dictionary:

d((W, n)] = k

Here k = optimal value we can obtain (with n elements under capacity W) + the value op obtained by traversing from last element to nth element

This led to series of bad lookup’s from the dictionary.

This resulted in erroneous answer for this test case in the second code.